# How to declare printf()?

Tags: c, printf

I wanted to print something using printf() function in C, without including stdio.h, so I wrote program as :

```
int printf(char *, ...);
int main(void)
{
        printf("hello world\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Is the above program correct ?

Comment: Your format string should be `const char*`. You could just locate `stdio.h` and read the definition there. Why, out of curiosity, don't you want to `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: how do you expect to print anything on the screen without including stdio.h ?? You'll have to write your own libraries .. it's suicidal :)

Comment: @bemace @Vic The act of including `stdio.h` doesn't link anything, header files don't work that way. This question is completely valid, and will work just fine.

Comment: @meager : It was just a quiz question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct declaration (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) is:

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ... );
```

But it would be easiest and safest to just `#include <stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 13):

Just:

```
man 3 printf
```

It will tell you `printf` signature:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

this is the right one.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this.

But it should be `const char *`.

Comment: @Oli : Does only char* affect anything ?

Comment: @Charles: In C99, yes.  That won't compile for anything earlier.

Comment: @Charles Just `const char*` here.

Comment: @Happy Yes, it defines a completely different function than `printf(const char*,...)`.

Comment: @meager : If I don't write const, then isn't it guaranteed that library's printf is called ?

Comment: @meagar: This is not C++. I agree it's *wrong* to omit the `const`, but it does not "define a completely different function", only an incorrect prototype for the same function. (I suspect this wrong prototype is actually guaranteed to work anyway, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: @Happy Mittal: If you don't include all the required type qualifiers then you have provided a function prototype that isn't compatible with the function definition. C doesn't have function overloading so you can't be referring to any other function but attempting to call it with an incompatible prototype in scope technically leads to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of the declaration:

```
extern int printf (__const char *__restrict __format, ...);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
int printf(char *, ...);
```

works just fine, I don't know why people are telling you that char needs to be a const