# Pass varargs to printf

Tags: c, function, variadic-functions, printf

I'd like to have a helper function `log` that essentially does the following:

```
log(file, "array has %d elements\n", 10);
// writes "2014-02-03 16:33:00 - array has 10 elements" to &file
```

I have the [time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3673291/732016) portion down, and I have the file writing portion down. However, the problem is the method signature itself for `log` — what should I put? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178966/732016) says that the `printf` declaration ends with the `...` keyword, but how can I use this in my function?

```
void log(FILE *f, const char * format, ...) // how would I pass ... to fprintf?
```

---

Let me **EDIT** this to include a bit more information.

I have a `const char * now ()` that returns a string of the form "2014-02-03 16:33:00." I would like to pass another format string in like this. The two statements should be equivalent:

```
log(file, "array has %d elements\n", 10);
fprintf(file, "%s - array has %d elements\n", now(), 10);
```

I know that `vfprintf` allows me to pass a `va_list`, but how can I put the `now()` as the first argument, *before* all the others?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `vprintf`, which is declared as:

```
int vprintf(const char *format, va_list ap);
```

In your `log` function, invoke `va_start` to obtain a `va_list` value, then pass that value to `vprintf`.

Since your `log` function takes a `FILE*` argument, you'll probably want to use `vfprintf` rather than `vprintf` (and perhaps update your question to ask about `fprintf` rather than `printf`).

Incidentally, you might want to reconsider using the name `log`; that's the name of a standard function declared in `<math.h>`.

Reflecting your updated question, you can print the timestamp inside `log` by calling `fprintf` directly:

```
va_list(args);
fprintf(f, "%s - ", now());
va_start(args, format);
vfprintf(f, format, args);
```

Comment: Thanks; I've edited my question to clarify the issue with va_list.

Comment: This doc http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start says your `format` has to be a `int` (amount of args to parse). How do you explain this diff?

Comment: OK!!!! I see. The 2nd arg can be wtf. va_start just searches what comes after.

Comment: @Sandburg: `va_start` is a macro, not a function. The second argument is the name of the parameter preceding the `, ...` in the function definition. In the example http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start, that parameter happens to be `int count`. `va_start()` doesn't look at the value of its second argument, it just needs its name to know where to start scanning.

Answer (score 19):

The method you are looking for is `vfprintf` or possible `vprintf` (unclear which by your question)

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vfprintf/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/

This is essentially the implementation of `printf` that allows a `va_list` to be explicitly passed in as a parameter.  So in your method you can create the `va_list` for your method parameters and forward it onto `vfprintf`

```
void log(FILE* f, const char* format, ...) { 
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  vfprintf (f, format, args);
  va_end (args);
}
```

Comment: `vfprintf` corresponds to `fprintf`; `vprintf` corresponds to `printf`. (The question is unclear about which one the OP needs.)

Comment: @KeithThompson good call, updated to include both references

Comment: Thanks; I've edited my question to clarify the issue with va_list.